# When do we use $\le$ or $\ge$ sign?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This might sound really dumb question but I came across this sentence from "**Elementary mathematics**" by Dorofeev , Potapov & Rozov that -

> Yet the understanding of the sign $\le$ between concrete numbers signifies that not a specific number can be substituted in place of $x$ in the inequality $x\le 3$, which is to say that $\le$ cannot be used to relate to any numbers whatsoever.

So does this means that we can't use $\le$ or $\ge$ for anything other than variables?

Comment: I have no idea what that quote means.  I'd say that $2≤5$ is perfectly true, if not terribly informative.

Comment: @lulu But 2<5 and the equality operator doesn't holds here so how can we can say that 2<=5 ?

Comment: Because it is true.  $2$ is indeed "less than or equal to $5$".  Granted you may know an even better result, namely that $2$ is less than $5$.  But that doesn't make the first result false.

Comment: Both "$2<5$" and "$2\leq 5$" are true.  We can also say "$2$ and $5$ are both real numbers" which is also a true statement.  Just because the one statement provides more information than the others does not mean that the others are incorrect or not useful.

Comment: @JMoravitz We can also think of 2<=5 as not a single statement but as disjunction of two statements - (2<5)OR(2=5) where OR represents disjunction and if that's the case then 2<=5 will actually be true because even when 2=5 is false even then 2<5 is true and so 2<=5 is true (at least in the logical sense).

Comment: Yes... and?$~~$

Comment: I've edited your question to use proper MathJax formatting.  For the future, please have a look at [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  Your questions are likely to be much better received if you format them appropriately.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hey , the problem with the logic of "Disjunction" is that Disjunction is true when both the mathematical statements are true but that's not possible because x<y and x=y both cannot be true simultaneously according to law of trichotomy so Is logic of Disjunction still valid ?

Comment: It is completely and totally irrelevant that they cannot be simultaneously true.  All that matters is that *at least one* of them is true.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hey but don't you think that if we actually omit one entire rule for Disjunction (when both the statements are true then disjunction is also true) because the rule is not valid in this condition then logically it's not disjunction.

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi But neither condition is being omitted!  Either $a < b$ OR $a = b$ OR both.  The fact that both cannot actually be true at the same time doesn't alter the underlying reasoning.

Answer (score 7):

You are quoting the book out of context (and seemingly quoting it incorrectly, as well).  The passage you quote is from the opening remarks of the text, where the authors admonish the reader to make sure that they are grokking the fundamental concepts (and not just the algorithmic or computational rules).  A more lengthy quote is as follows:

> The student [i.e. the reader] will also recall the signs of weak inequalities $\le$ (less than or equal to) and $\ge$ (greater than or equal to).  The student usually finds no difficulty when using them in formal transformations, but examinations have shown that many students do not fully comprehend their meaning.
>
> To illustrate, a frequent answer to: "*Is the inequality $2\le 3$ true?*" is "No, since the number 2 is less than 3".  Or, say, "*Is the inequality $3\le 3$ true?*" the answer is often "No, since 3 is equal to 3".  Nevertheless, students who answer in this fashion are often found to write the result of a problem $x\le 3$.  Yet their understanding of the $\le$ sign between concrete numbers signifies that not a single specific number can be substituted in place of $x$ in the inequality $x\le 3$, which is to say that the $\le$ sign cannot be used to relate any numbers whatsoever.

Notice that the authors are discussing a common error that students of mathematics make.  They are not declaring that $2 \not\le 3$ or that $3 \not\le 3$.  Instead, they are pointing out that many students, lacking a fundamental understanding of what these symbols mean, will mistakenly declare that it cannot be that $2\le 3$ because $2 < 3$.

They continue and explain this in a bit more detail:

> Actually, the situation is this:  by *definition* of the sign $\le$, the *inequality $a\le b$ is considered to be true when $a<b$ and also when $a=b$*.  Thus, the inequality $2\le 3$ is *true* because 2 *is less* than 3, and the inequality $3\le 3$ is *true* because 3 *is equal* to 3.
>
> From this definition of the sign $\le$ it follows that the inequality $a\le b$ is not true only when $a > b$.  For this reason, the sign $\le$ may be read not only as "less than or equal to" but also as "not greater than".  Thus the inequalities $2\le 3$ and $3\le 3$ are read, respectively, "2 is not greater than 3" and "3 is not greater than 3".

This second reading of the inequality might be a more useful one to keep in mind.  Instead of trying to keep track of a disjunction (which requires keeping track of two statements), it might be easier to keep track of a single statement.  That is, $a \le b$ is the negation of the statement $a > b$.  In other words $a \le b$ means identically the same thing as $\lnot(a>b)$, i.e. "$a$ is not greater than $b$."  The same reasoning applies to $a \ge b$.

Answer (score 2):

We use $\geqslant$, and $\leqslant$ while solving equations using variables. For example 3x $\geqslant$ 6, and similarly $\leqslant$. It can also be used for concrete numbers like 4 $\geqslant$ 3, however it is understood that 4>3 so we just remove the = sign. Moreover, one can also use 4$\geqslant$ 4 but, it is pre-understood that 4=4 so we remover the > sign. In each of the case the statement is true.

Comment: "*so we just remove the = sign*" should be replaced with something more along the lines of "*so we have the option to just remove the = sign (but by no means are required to do so)*"

Comment: We remove signs in case we have the knowledge that it is universally true. For example we write only 3 instead of 3x1 which is also true. Similarly one can use those signs according to the requirements.

Comment: But again, it is an *option* to do so and we are not required to do so.  Sometimes it is even helpful *to* rewrite things with an extra multiplication of one so that certain properties and theorems become more obvious.  For example $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k\cdot 1 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k\cdot 1^{n-k} = (2+1)^n = 3^n$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ordering symbols for both numbers and variables. Variables, after all, are meant to represent numbers.

Read $x \le y$ as $x$ *is less than OR equal to* $y$. In this context, *OR* is the logical disjunction which evaluates to true in the case of $x<y$, true in the case of $x=y$, and false otherwise.

Then $2 \le 3$ is true, as is the simpler version $2<3$.

Comment: Will it still be logical disjunction ? Because one entire condition that the disjunction of two statements will be true when both the statements are true but technically both the statements can't be true in this case so it is still called disjunction or we have a different name for it ??

Comment: Good question. Not sure if it has another name, but it seems like the definition of the logical OR still applies. We just don't end up with the case where both statements are true.